# Is there an iPhone library to provide something similar to an iPad popover?

Tags: iphone, ipad, popover

Is there some library that provides a UIView/UIViewController similar to the iPad popover on the iPhone? I'm just talking about a temporary view that appears on top of the current view, and does the nice transitions that a UIPopoverView does on an iPad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to complete the question. A iPhone popover implementation is hosted on GitHub: [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this on also. 
Click here to download [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover)