# Creating a popover on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to create a custom-style popover on the iphone. I want it to have an arrowhead pointing upwards. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an iPhone library to provide something similar to an iPad popover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692460/is-there-an-iphone-library-to-provide-something-similar-to-an-ipad-popover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an UIView that kooks like what you want (it can be transparent backgroud with an UIImageView that is your arrow) and use an UIAnimation to make it pop (scale it little->big->little for instance).
It should do the trick?

Comment: I could do this. The main problem I see with this is that I wish to have a semi-transparent border to the whole thing, and this won't travel around the arrow. If i try and give the arrow this border, stopping just in the right place, i'm sure this wouldn't look right and would cause graphical issues.

Comment: you can incorporate this semi transparent border in your image and it will look fine :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover)
It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When ever You click on any button to open popoverview...then take the frame of that button ...using that frame u have to set the frame of your custom popoverview..All The Best!!