# Creating a custom popover for iPhone - what class do I subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I saw this question here ([How to create popover in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547969/how-to-create-popover-in-iphone-app)), and wanted to design a class that could create a popover object, I find all the libraries for popovers right now aren't doing quite what I'd like to do.

So I figure I'll create my own, but I'm a little new at it. Do I subclass UIView directly? Could anyone point me in the right direction for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass `UIView`.  Implement the `layerClass` class method of your custom UIView subclass and return `[CAShapeLayer class]` (from the QuartzCore framework), or use your own subclass of `CAShapeLayer` instead of CAShapeLayer itself.  In your UIView subclass' implementation of `initWithFrame:` you can set the view's layer's path to get the popover shape you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a popover by subclassing is one of the way to achieve your goal, even its a simple matter of doing google as there are may solutions on StackOverflow about the same.

Take a look at this answer [This will help you to proceed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11827712/742815)