# iBooks style settings popup window

Tags: iphone, ios, popup, popupwindow

Does anybody know how it has been realized? I have found many topics about popups for iPhone (alert style, etc.), but this case is more complicated for my opinion. In iBooks we see shadows, arrow and borders. This window closes after tapping outside borders.

PS Can't post image here, but I have found an example:
http://chamberfour.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ibooks.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, back some time ago I had to face a similar problem. Strictly speaking, what we see there is a *popover*, but the documentation explicitly states that `UIPopoverController` may only be used in an iPad application so you will probably have to do what I did: implement your own or, perhaps better, find an open source implementation (there should be plenty of them out there).

Comment: I have found the similar theme with the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547969/how-to-create-popover-in-iphone-app There we can find an interesting approach - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11827712/742815 Is it accepted by Apple team? Does anybody use it?